# website not working over IPv6 ISP

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ipv6, ipv4, iis-8.5

I have domain example.com which is hosted over window server 2012 R2, IIS 8.5.

My web server is IPv6 enabled, online tools are able to resolve my domain over both IPv4 and IPv6,

My website is working fine over IPv4 ISP,when i enter example.com in URL it automatically redirect me to https://www.example.com (I have written code in `web.config` to redirect http to https and non www to www), and functioning as expected.

but when i open my domain example.com over IPv6 ISP, It is showing me Error "Not Found HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found" , it is not even redirecting to https://www.example.com

Can any one suggest anything on this ?

Comment: Please provide the real domain name so we can check if anything is wrong with the DNS records.

Comment: did you bind the ipv6 address to iis8.5? is it a global unicast address?  can you access it directly via `https://[2001:db8::10]`

Comment: Yeah, I think you need to check your binding in IIS as Jacob suggested.

Comment: @Appleoddity   IT is resolve now, it was binding issue